# Tailwind CSS and JS is not working on GitHub page

Tags: javascript, css, github

Tailwind CSS and JavaScript is not working on my GitHub pages.

Here is my GitHub page link https://slug01.github.io/keep-notes/

https://slug01.github.io/keep-notes/

Comment: did you add the CDN links of tailwaind css in your html file ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably forget to add CDN link in your head tag inside html add this tag inside your head tag and than you are good to goo...

```
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

Comment: still it is not working sir Here is the code can u check it once please https://github.com/slug01/keep-notes

Comment: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn  this will help you follow the steps

Answer (score 0):

In addition of the DCN link, you have in your [`index.html`](https://github.com/slug01/keep-notes/blob/d4b1532002371cf2a1aeb694a68afc6c887383f2/index.html#L7=) a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dest/output.css">`

As in [this thread](https://github.community/t/css-not-being-applied-in-pages/10466), use a relative path to refer to your file, e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="dest/output.css">`.

Or `../dest/...` for your sub-pages

Comment: Sir can you check it once,i have added all those links  here is the link https://github.com/slug01/keep-notes

Comment: @ArabindraDhami I still see absolute instead of relative path in [`index.html` line 7](https://github.com/slug01/keep-notes/blob/640c1fd8dfda3c9b243e8410bc211c5d82ed5676/index.html#L7). You need `<link rel="stylesheet" href="dest/output.css">` as mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually using Tailwind CDN is a great way when I'm in the process of building a website, at first I struggled to add custom colors and fonts, but after seeing this I can.

use this code in your CDN link, give it a try

```
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com?plugins=forms,typography,aspect-ratio,line-clamp"></script>
```

then in the head for complete like this:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Customized Tailwind Colors and Fonts</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com?plugins=forms,typography,aspect-ratio,line-clamp"></script>
  
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Outfit:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
  
  <script>    
   tailwind.config = {  
    darkMode: 'class', // or 'media'  
    theme: {   
     display: ["group-hover"],
     extend: {
      fontFamily: {
       sans: ['Outfit',],
     },
     colors:({ colors }) => ({
       custom : colors.cyan,
     }), 
    }, 
   }, 
  } 
  </script> 
 </head>
```

You can change the color and the photo, for more details you can see the tutorial here
https://www.92pixels.com/tutorial/how-to-use-customized-tailwind-colors-and-fonts/